# Angular ui-select multiple clean ng-model value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend, ui-select

I am trying to use the ui-select and the component is cleaning my array.

Example:

```
{{ vm.staff_hotels }}
<ui-select multiple ng-model="x" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Not selected">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="hotel.id as hotel in vm.hotels | filter: {active: true} | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="hotel.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

My variable "vm.staff_hotels" value on screen is [1,2].

```
{{ vm.staff_hotels }}
<ui-select multiple ng-model="vm.staff_hotels" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Not selected">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="hotel.id as hotel in vm.hotels | filter: {active: true} | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="hotel.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

but, if I use the variable in ng-model my value change to [null,null].

Comment: Are there hotels with id 1 and 2?

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue.

Comment: that is the problem, I have the same code working well in another controller, so, I need to know why this CAN happening, because it is not a default behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just need to update the version of my ui-select.

I used to use version 0.10.0

I updated to version 0.11.2

Just a bug!

Comment: Six to give up 50 to find that out. Glad you got it back